# Pandas elapsed time between 2 date order by user

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a fake bank dataset who look like this :

```
Card Number                  Date                 Amount 
536518******2108      2015-05-01 00:01:54          55.0   
536518******2191      2015-05-01 00:01:14          37.5  
536518******2108      2015-05-01 00:02:34          105.2 
536518******2191      2015-05-01 00:03:14          75.0
```

I want to calculate the elapsed time between 2 transactions

So my code look like this :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as st

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')

position = df.columns.get_loc('Date')
df.groupby(df['Card Number'])
df['elapsed'] =  df.iloc[1:, position] - df.iat[0, position]
df["elapsed"] = df['elapsed'].dt.components['seconds']
```

But this calculates the elapsed time between 2 `'Date'` without caring about the "Card Number".
I don't know how I can reset the last time save when I switch to another user.
I guess that I need to modify the value in my `iloc[]` and `iat[]` but I can't figure out how to do that.
My output should look like this :

```
Card Number                  Date                 Amount       elapsed
536518******2108      2015-05-01 00:01:54          55.0           0         -> first transaction (...2108)
536518******2191      2015-05-01 00:01:14          37.5           0         -> first transaction (...2191)
536518******2108      2015-05-01 00:02:34          105.2          40        -> second transaction from ...2108
536518******2191      2015-05-01 00:03:14          75.0           120       -> second transaction from ...2191
```

I also have to calculate how many transactions a Card do in a 30 minutes gap of time.
In SQL, it should look like this :

```
df["transactions_30"] = df.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM df OVER (PARTITION BY 'Card Number' ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN '30 minutes' PRECEDING AND '0 minutes' FOLLOWING)")
```

This code return `invalid syntax`, how can I avoid using SQL query to execute the following request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert "Date" to pandas datetime object; then `groupby` "Card Number" and find `diff`; use the `.dt` accessor to get elapsed time in the seconds:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['elapsed'] = df.groupby('Card Number')['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds().fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
        Card Number                Date  Amount  elapsed
0  536518******2108 2015-05-01 00:01:54    55.0      0.0
1  536518******2191 2015-05-01 00:01:14    37.5      0.0
2  536518******2108 2015-05-01 00:02:34   105.2     40.0
3  536518******2191 2015-05-01 00:03:14    75.0    120.0
```